# Can we add Button or link on Object manager navigation pane?

Tags: home-page-component, setup-object

I'm wondering if we can edit or update the home page for "Setup-> Object Manager"?

[image]

URL is {MyDomain}/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Account/Details/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There are only a few things you can do in Setup to customize Setup, such as toggling the old Profile view and the new one. Unlike the main app, Setup pages cannot be customized in this manner.

Comment: I saw a video of one of the apps EasyCrudV2 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7rFV1QRQyg&t=2s&ab_channel=RaviNarayanan) and in that demo video, they had two links appeared under there.

Comment: Ok nvm. It's a chrome extension and not a salesforce App. Thank you @sfdcfox.

Comment: @Watson You're welcome!